# Capitalization of umlauts using BibLaTeX style ieee-alphabetic

Tags: biblatex, capitalization, ieee-style

**Update:** As pointed out in the [linked page](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/issues/32) found below in the comments, the problem I describe is caused by `biber` and is promised to be fixed in version `2.8 DEV`.

So I don't expect there will be another satisfying answer.

---

---

I have my problems to get German umlauts capitalized correctly in the references.

Here is the minimal non-working example:

> The bibliography file `ref.bib`:

```
@Article{   ÜüzÜdÜ,
  author  = {\"Uding, G\"unther},
  title   = {\"Uber {\"{U}}berlegungen zur \"{U}berwindung des {Ü}bels},
  year    = {1996}
}
```

> The main TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
 \nocite{*}
 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output I get is:

[image]

Of course, I'd like it to read "Über Überlegungen zur Überwindung des Übels" instead.

Comment: Already here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233971

Comment: That's not exactly my problem here. Capitalization works perfectly for non-umlauts with `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17`and `biber 2.6`. (But I know the problem you mention, since I always run into it when compiling a LaTeX file on my university computer.)

Comment: I'll take a look: must still have the brace retention incorrect in one step.

Comment: https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/issues/32

Comment: Going by the title, this is a really profound philosophical treatise -- it should be cited more often.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has already been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233971), see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20335). I illustrate the solution:

### ref.bib

- I used the umlauts directly.
- I protected the title by using two extra pairs of curly brackets (**three** pairs in total).
- I don't know why one extra pair of curly brackets is not enough. I guess that the issue [here](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/issues/32) has something to do with it (it was mentioned/created in the comment of the question above).

Code:

```
@Article{Article01,
  author  = {Üding, Günther},
  title   = {Über Überlegungen zur Überwindung des Übels},
  year    = {1996}
}

@Article{Article02,
  author  = {Üding, Günther},
  title   = {{{Über Überlegungen zur Überwindung des Übels}}},
  year    = {1996}
}
```

### Main Document

- Here I changed the encoding.
- I also use babel for the correct reference string (*Literatur* in German)
- I added the famous `csquotes` package for better quotes.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}  

\usepackage[
    backend = biber, 
    style = ieee-alphabetic
    ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
 \nocite{*}
 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, using three enclosing braces `{{{ .... }}}` gives the correct capitalization (I only tried two `{{ .... }}` before). Even though I'm not really satisfied to use this workaround.

Comment: @JohnnyTeX Glad I could help. I also find it strange.